# Bteq Scripts to copy data between two Teradata servers

Tags: sql, teradata

How do I copy data from multiple tables within one database to another database residing on a different server?

Is this possible through a BTEQ Script in Teradata?

If so, provide a sample.

If not, are there other options to do this other than using a flat-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question, you want to move a set of tables from one DB to another.

You can use the following syntax in a BTEQ Script to copy the tables and data:

`CREATE TABLE <NewDB>.<NewTable> AS <OldDB>.<OldTable> WITH DATA AND STATS;`

Or just the table structures:

`CREATE TABLE <NewDB>.<NewTable> AS <OldDB>.<OldTable> WITH NO DATA AND NO STATS;`

If you get real savvy you can create a BTEQ script that dynamically builds the above statement in a SELECT statement, exports the results, then in turn runs the newly exported file all within a single BTEQ script.

There are a bunch of other options that you can do with `CREATE TABLE <...> AS <...>;`. You would be best served reviewing the Teradata Manuals for more details.

Comment: Didn't catch the two physical instances in the original question. My answer works for copying tables on the same physical instance. Therefore, should not be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible using BTEQ since you have mentioned both the databases are residing in different servers.

There are two solutions for this.

- **Arcmain** - You need to use Arcmain Backup first, which creates files containing data from your tables. Then you need to use Arcmain restore which restores the data from the files
- **TPT** - **Teradata Parallel Transporter.** This is a very advanced tool. This does not create any files like Arcmain. It directly moves the data between two teradata servers.[(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teradata_Parallel_Transporter)

Comment: Just caught the different server blip in his question. Arcmain would be the easiest. TPT sounds a lot like NPARC which moved data using named pipes between the two systems.

Comment: @Rob Okay. I have seen you in teradataquestions.com Where do you work?

Comment: Right now I am an independent consultant working as a Lead DBA on a Teradata data warehouse.

Comment: Are ArcMain and TPT only availiable typically to users with "DBA" permissions?

Comment: For ArcMain- archive needs read access on your tables and restore needs write access on the new target tables. 
For TPT - Yes, you need advanced permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more options which will allow you to copy from one table to another.

Possibly the simplest way would be to write a smallish program which uses one of their communication layers (ODBC, .NET Data Provider, JDBC, cli, etc.) and use that to take a select statement and an insert statement. This would require some work, but it would have less overhead than trying to learn how to write TPT scripts. You would not need any 'DBA' permissions to write your own.

Teradata also sells other applications which hides the complexity of some of the tools. Teradata Data Mover handles provides an abstraction layer between tools like arcmain and tpt. Access to this tool is most likely restricted to DBA types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move data from one server to another server then
We can do this with the flat file.
First we have fetch data from source table to flat file through any utility such as bteq or fastexport.
then we can load this data into target table with the help of mload,fastload or bteq scripts.